# Why can’t I define a command with \renewcommand?

Tags: macros

I try use boolean expresion which it has been shown on my MNWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, b4paper, twoside]{scrbook}   
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse} 
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsbsy} 

\newbool{pboldvectors}%
\booltrue{pboldvectors}%

\ifbool{pboldvectors}%
  {\renewcommand{\vecc}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}}                      % then clausule
  {\renewcommand{\vecc}[1]{\vec{#1}}}                         % else clausule

\begin{document} 
  \begin{equation}
     \vecc{x}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but without success. I have got Latex error: \vecc is undefinned. Before, I used the library ifthen, but it has been obsolete. I would like to use this switch for mathematical formatting.

Comment: Simply `\vecc` has never been defined. So use `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @jafan: Please accept karl’s instead, He was the first one an I can’t delete mine as long it is marked as accepted.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with either `koma-script`, `etoolbox` or `conditionals`. Both tags and title of the question are quite misleading...

Comment: @cgnieder: I tried to fix it, do you agree with my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `\renewcomad` a command must be defined before. Use `\newcommand` instead ...

Comment: This was already in my comment...

Comment: @karlkoeller: Sorry I over read this (answered from my smart phone …). Why don’t you extend you comment a little an make an answer out of it? I’ll delete mine ;-)

Comment: OK, I will now...

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `\renewcommand` when a command has never been defined before, as in the case of `\vecc`.

In these cases you have to use `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand`.

So the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, b4paper, twoside]{scrbook}   
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse} 
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsbsy} 

\newbool{pboldvectors}%
\booltrue{pboldvectors}%

\ifbool{pboldvectors}%
  {\newcommand{\vecc}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}}                      % then clausule
  {\newcommand{\vecc}[1]{\vec{#1}}}                         % else clausule

\begin{document} 
  \begin{equation}
     \vecc{x}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

will work.